# Hiding an echo after clicking a dropdown tag in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have the below code that will show the count of notifications. I need to hide the number upon clicking the dropdown menu.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
                data-toggle="dropdown" 
                role="button" 
                aria-haspopup="true" 
                aria-expanded="false"
     >
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
          Notifications 
          <span class="badge">{{count(auth()->user()->notifics)}}</span>
     </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
```

Comment: just hide badge as `$('.badge').hide()` onclick

Comment: what are the item of the dropdown menu

Comment: This is more related to html/css/js rather than php and laravel, you should fix the tags to be visible to the right people;) btw @DevsiOdedra posted the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are not using jQuery, so I used pure javascript for the answer.

If you want to **completely remove** the badge then use this:
Set your `<a>` tag like this:

```
<a href="#" id="button_id" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>Notifications <span class="badge">{{count(auth()->user()->notifics)}}</span></a>
```

Then using javascript:

```
<script>document.getElementById("button_id").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("button_id").innerHTML = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-globe'></span>Notifications";
});
</script>
```

If you want to **temporarily hide** the badge then:

Set your `<a>` tag like this:

```
<a href="#" id="button_id" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>Notifications <span id="hide_me" class="badge">{{count(auth()->user()->notifics)}}</span></a>
```

And use this javascript code to hide it:

```
<script>document.getElementById("button_id").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("hide_me").style.display = "none";
});
</script>
```

To show it back, use:

```
document.getElementById("hide_me").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Please note, that this will not hide the element, but destroy it. If you would like to show it at some point, you should use some of the hide mechanics. But if not, this is better, as it will not exist altogether.

Comment: Thank you @MartinDimitrov. I edited my answer to include both deletion and hiding of the element.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to hide the `<span class="badge">` element.
There are many ways to do this.
One of them is using jQuery as follows

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
  $('.badge').hide();
});
```

You can use a vanilla JS onclick event also, if you prefer to not use jQuery and change add either `style="display:none"` or `hidden` to the element.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I was already writing this when you commented it. Besides, there are other options mentioned in the answer. You can consider it expanding of your answer. I also gave him a ready code to copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <div id="itemStatus"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>Notifications <span class="badge">{{count(auth()->user()->notifics)}}</span></a></div>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" onclick="showFunction()">
<li>
```

//javascript

```
<script>
function showFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("itemStatus");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```